# Combine values from two different object keys into one object key value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects coming from an api that looks like this

```
[{"HomeTeam": "HOU"}, {"AwayTeam": "GB"}, {"HomeTeam": "DAL"}, {"AwayTeam": "TB"}]
```

I'm using map to map over the objects and get the team names to put them into react table like this.

```
const results = data.map((teams) => ({
    "Teams": // I need both teams here
}))
```

How can I map over the array and get both `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` values into `Teams` values?

I need the final object to look like this

```
[{"Teams": "HOU"}, {"Teams": "GB"}, {"Teams": "DAL"}, {"Teams": "TB"}]
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your desired outcome is, but I feel that the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method would help you

Comment: That's a horrible api. Use `data.flatMap(Object.entries)` then work with the tuples

Comment: `const results = data.map(team => ({ Teams: team.HomeTeam || team.AwayTeam }));`

Comment: As _Bergi_ said, this is a very bad API, the response should be at least like: `{ team: Name, type: HomeTeam/AwayTeam }` or return a match object like so: `{ HomeTeam: Name, AwayTeam: Name }`

Comment: Didn't build the api so I have no control over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objects only have one key, this should be fine.

```js
const data = [{"HomeTeam": "HOU"}, {"AwayTeam": "GB"}, {"HomeTeam": "DAL"}, {"AwayTeam": "TB"}];

const results = data.map(td => ({ Teams: Object.values(td)[0] }));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: ...or use `Object.values` like so: `{ Teams: Object.values(td)[0] }`.

Comment: Yes, that's cleaner. I'll edit with your suggestion.